# Timer Class In Console Application C#

Tags: c#, timer

```
public class PacketPoller
{
    private Timer m_timer;

    public void Start()
    {
        m_timer = new Timer(OnTick(null), null, 0, 1);
        m_timer.InitializeLifetimeService();
    }

    public Action<Object> OnTick() { }
}
```

This is my code, however, the timer seems to require a `static`method, rather than an object-oriented method. What can I do about it? I want to user to be able to create a new Timer and then change it's OnTick to set the method to call. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the [`Tick` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to wire arbitrary methods whenever it ticks. EDIT: Nevermind, I think I linked to a different `Timer` class than the one you're using.

Comment: Are you getting compilation errors?  Try replacing this: `m_timer = new Timer(OnTick(null), null, 0, 1);` with this: `m_timer = new Timer(OnTick, null, 0, 1);`

Comment: What Timer are you using?  There is System.Windows.Forms.Timer. System.Threading.Timer, and System.Timers.Timer...  If you're using Systme.Windows.Forms.Timer, that won't work in a console app.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Should work fine in a console application, as long as you reference the `Windows.Forms` assembly.

Comment: @Jite, not unless you create a message pump (i.e. open a form)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've successfully used recently.

```
        DispatcherTimer timer1stDoze = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        timer1stDoze.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1stDoze_Tick);
        timer1stDoze.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        timer1stDoze.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using the `System.Timers.Timer` class.
I would recommend trying with the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class instead. It do not require a static callback function and is a bit easier to work with (easier to debug due to it not being threaded).
This will require a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly tho.

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(CallbackFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to stick with the `System.Threading.Timer`, have it as you have, but have your `PacketPoller` have its own event that you'll fire in conjunction:

```
public class PacketPoller
{
    public event EventHandler Tick;

    private Timer m_timer;

    public void Start()
    {
        m_timer = new Timer(OnTick, null, 0, 1);
        m_timer.InitializeLifetimeService();
    }

    public void OnTick(object state) 
    { 
        var tick = this.Tick;
        if (tick != null)
            tick();
    }
}
```

Listeners will be wired to your `PacketPoller.Tick` event rather than the `m_timer` directly. I'm assuming you don't have a state to bubble through, but if you need to you can pass it through. (notice I modified the method signature of `OnTick` and your constructor call as well)